# grid-template-columns from end of text

Tags: css, css-grid

I have grid that looks like this: [image]

with the css:

```
display: grid;
float: left;
gap: 18px;
grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
margin-top: 10px;
```

Is there a way to shorten the distance between Text1 and the start of Text2 long bla...?
(using the grid css and not matgin: -12px for example)
It seems like the distance between them is the width of Text2 long bla... (which is the longest element here)?

thank you!

Comment: what you can do is create grid of 3 or maybe 4 column. And assign only one column to text 1 and rest to text 2

Comment: it should be dynamic
a different grid can have "Text3 very long dsfdfgjkdfhgkjfhdjk gfdjghkdf" instead of Text1, or short text in "Text2 long bla..." place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `repeat(2, 1fr)` will divide the *container* into *2 equal parts*. So if you want to lower the distance between them, you should change your *container*s width.

```css
.firstContainer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.secondContainer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<section class="firstContainer">
    <span>Hello</span>
    <span>, World!</span>
</section>

<section class="secondContainer">
    <span>Hello</span>
    <span>, World!</span>
</section>
```